# Android - String returns empty when called outside of the http get method.

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a string id, I assign the string inside the http client.OnSuccess method.

```
    public static void getInfo(String age, Info al){
    final String URL = "url";
    final AsyncHttpClient client2 = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client2.get(URL, null, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {

            parser();//where I parser the xml files
            age = Al.getAge();

        }
    });

Log.d("Age", age);//age become null here.
```

}

How can I assess the value of age outside the OnSuccess method?

Comment: The reason it returns empty is because the program pointer is not waiting for client.get to finish being executed. It keeps going and exits your function. When I get a time, I will try to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Log.d("Age", age); is executing before onSuccess execute. So best way to use the age outside the onSuccess is

create a method outside and print the log in that method and call that method from onsuccess.

Log.d("Age", age); wont wait untill onsucess is execute so ur getting it null

Comment: Thank you :).This is what I was doing, and I was trying to call the server three times, the codes get very long.